# Magento EE order comments not being saved when using Paypal

Tags: magento-enterprise, onepage-checkout

We are using Magento EE v 1.14.0.1 and we have a One Page checout plugin that aside from enabling us to have our checkout all on one page. It also has a order comments box.

Our issue is if the customer pays via Credit card (we use Authorize.net for this) the order comments are saved. However if the customer chooses to pay via Paypal then the system does not seem to save the order comments content?

Anyway suggestions what might be the issue or what file would need to be edited to get this to work?
I am using a one page checkout plugin
https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/magento-one-step-checkout-module.html